# Receive FCM when device connected only to WiFi

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**How to disable receiving push notification when device use mobile data?** 

It needed to save user's traffic and money.

I have one suggestion about this.
Need register `BroadcastReceiver` which will track `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and if WiFi is turn off call `InstanceID.deleteToken()` but I'm not sure about this approach.
Maybe there is some method that doing this stuff?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a broadcast receiver to determine network type and unregister using `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("yourTopic");`

Answer (score 1):

You can register new firebase topics by https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance

When you connected with wifi use this : FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

And when you are using mobile network :
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");

Or maybe you can use this :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", Log.getStackTraceString(e) );
                RxBus.getInstance().post(new OffPushError());
            }
    });
```

thread.start();

Answer (score 1):

Your approach (un-registering when Wifi goes off and re-registering when Wifi goes on) may result in an unexpected behavior. Well I don't know the nature of the project you're working on, but most of the time it will affect.

Assume the Wifi goes off and you un-register, then a message is pushed by the server to devices (your device won't be one of them because it has un-registered) and then your Wifi goes on and registers a new token, your previous message won't deliver to your device. This is in case of general messages (sent to all devices for example).

But also your device will lose its history in your server (again, this depends on your project).

A possible solution could be that: when Wifi goes offline and you want to restrict cellular network (meaning cellular network is on) you can send a message to your server indicating that the device is offline. And when your server wants to send message it checks devices' status. And when the Wifi goes on send a message saying you're online.

Comment: Yes, you right, unregister device not good solution. Probably I should review project conception and remove this "feature"